# Undefined objects in a Gruntfile for an old AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I have an old AngularJS (1) application that used to start fine.

After upgrading my dependencies yesterday, the `module` and `require` objects (among others) are now undefined.

```
// Generated on 2014-10-21 using generator-angular 0.9.8
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  ...

}
```

Here is my `bower.json` file content:

```
{
  "name": "nitro-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "*",
    "json3": "*",
    "es5-shim": "*",
    "stacktrace": "*",
    "firebase": "*",
    "angular-resource": "*",
    "angular-cookies": "*",
    "angular-sanitize": "*",
    "angular-animate": "*",
    "angular-touch": "*",
    "angular-route": "*",
    "angular-ui-router": "*",
    "angular-translate": "*",
    "angular-base64": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-utils-pagination": "*",
    "angular-ui-utils": "*",
    "angular-file-upload": "*",
    "a0-angular-storage": "*",
    "sockjs": "*",
    "stomp-websocket": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "*",
    "angular-scenario": "*",
    "karma-jasmine": "*"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "resolutions": {
    "es5-shim": "*",
    "angular": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-mocks": "*"
  }
}
```

And the `package.json` file content:

```
{
  "name": "nitroproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "*",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "*",
    "grunt-concurrent": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
    "grunt-filerev": "*",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "*",
    "grunt-karma": "*",
    "grunt-newer": "*",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "*",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "*",
    "grunt-svgmin": "*",
    "grunt-usemin": "*",
    "grunt-wiredep": "*",
    "jasmine-core": "*",
    "jshint-stylish": "*",
    "karma": "*",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "*",
    "karma-jasmine": "*",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "*",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.2",
    "time-grunt": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

I'm running node `6.8.1`.

No dependencies are outdated:

```
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X301 nitro-project]
$ npm outdated
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X301 nitro-project]
```

The console log shows loads of such lines:

```
Running "newer:jshint:all" (newer) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

Gruntfile.js
  line 2    col 1    Use the function form of "use strict".
  line 4    col 1    'module' is not defined.
  line 7    col 3    'require' is not defined.
  line 10   col 3    'require' is not defined.
  line 12   col 21   'require' is not defined.
  line 16   col 10   'require' is not defined.
  line 147  col 19   'require' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory I would try:

```
npm uninstall
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
```

A fresh install of your dependencies (especially Grunt) may be what you need. If not, it's worth a shot before more troubleshooting.

Comment: I just ran your `npm` commands but it didn't change anything to the issue.